# How to create an Intent method

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there any way to create a basic method, that enables me to create an intent with a few parameters.

```
public void setIntent(Class to, String key, String string) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, to);
    intent.putExtra(key, string);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

That was my primary idea but it isn't working. I'm not able to pass a class and I don't know if and how I could maybe pass an ajustable amount of extras with different variables.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to go to another class or to make an action to the class you are ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   // Generalized method
   private void startActivityGeneral(final Class<? extends Activity> activityToOpen , Bundle parameters){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext() , activityToOpen);
    for (String key : parameters.keySet()) {
        String params_key = key;
        String params_value = parameters.get(key).toString();
        // to bundle parameters based on type
        intent.putExtra(params_key ,params_value);
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}

    //Calling
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString("key1" , "value1");
    data.putString("key2" , "value2");
    startActivityGeneral(Main2Activity.class , data);
    //startActivityGeneral(Main3Activity.class , data);
```

For adjustable amount of extras with different variables - Use Bundle

Comment: What is the use of the colon in the for() loop?

Comment: That is a "for each loop"/ "enhanced for loop".

Answer (score 0):

You can create something like this.

```
public void setIntent() {
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, ActivityToGo.class);
intent.putExtra(key, "test");
startActivity(intent);
}
```

And then only you call this method wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

your idea is correct but you should pass nameActivity.class as parameter

```
     setIntent(nameActivity.class,"key","hello");
      ************************************************
      public void setIntent(Class to, String key, String string) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, to);
       intent.putExtra(key, string);
        startActivity(intent);
```